# Profiling a jar file remotely?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, profiling

Is there any profiler available in the java environment which can be used on a remote machine?
I have a .jar file (plain java code,nothing fancy) running on a remote machine and I want to profile that file. However,I can't install the profiler on the remote machine since I do not have the necessary permissions. Is there any way I can profile the application from my local machine?

Comment: how can you possibly "profile a JAR file"? it is just a file. You can profile code, not files :-P

Answer (score 2):

Aall Java profilers I know have that ability, since the Java debugging interface (JVMTI) is inherently network-capable.

[VisualVM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/intro.html) has basic (but often sufficient) profiling features and comes with the JDK.